# What is the purpose of "EntityPropertyName" property of field?

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api, spfield, odata, property

I am getting all list fields using REST API, In result, I found there is "**`EntityPropertyName`**" property for each field.

For some fields, it shows exactly same value as "**`InternalName`**" property But for some fields, it shows OData_InternalNameValue.

**See below results**

```
    <content type="application/xml">
      <m:properties>
      <d:EntityPropertyName>Additional_x0020_Software</d:EntityPropertyName>
        <d:InternalName>Additional_x0020_Software</d:InternalName>
        <d:Title>4-Software *</d:Title>
      </m:properties>
    </content>

<content type="application/xml">
      <m:properties>
        <d:EntityPropertyName>OData__x0033__x002d_Business_x0020_Req</d:EntityPropertyName>
        <d:InternalName>_x0033__x002d_Business_x0020_Req</d:InternalName>
        <d:Title>3-Business-Justification *</d:Title>
      </m:properties>
    </content>
```

I just want to know what is the purpose of "EntityPropertyName" property? and why there is "OData" string in `d:EntityPropertyName`.  I googled it but have not got satisfactory information.

I will be really appreciated if someone give information on it. Thanks

Comment: I'm also looking for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If your column name starts with a number or hex code, you can not get data with rest API by giving 'InternalName' name of fields for select, order, or any of operation.
That's why for some fields 'EntityPropertyName' starts with **OData_**.
I'm not pretty sure about every time we can use 'EntityPropertyName' instead of 'InternalName'.